# Redis save error

Tags: redis

I'm running

```
save 600 1
```

On my redis-cli to save every 10 minutes if at least 1 key has changed, however it's giving me:

```
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'save' command
```

I'm taking this example from redis's official website here: http://redis.io/topics/persistence

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing, understandably, two types of `save`s.

`save 600 1` is a Redis configuration directive - it can be specified in the .conf file or via the `CONFIG SET` command. This directive controls the automatic background snapshotting of data as explained.

On the other hand, Redis also offers the [`SAVE`](http://redis.io/commands/save) command (no arguments) that can be invoked via the cli or any client. This command causes Redis to save the dataset while blocking other operations.

**Note:** since `SAVE` is a blocking command you are advised against using it in production.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! Appreciate it. Used CONFIG SET and everything is wrong fine. Is there a way I can use BGSAVE like SAVE in config file?

Comment: I assume you mean that everything is *working* fine - good. The `save` config directive, when triggered, in fact does a non-blocking `BGSAVE`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, was tired...late at night. Awesome, good to know, thanks for your help again!